# django pagination by giving textbox inputs

Tags: django, pagination

I'm a new pratikant and when i joined in the company they gave me the task of configuring number of items per page by giving textbox input for example i created a textbox in html and submmit button and now i want to insert some value say 2 then it should show me first 2 records of the items in the same way 3, 4, 5 ,.......now for me the problem is i was unable to make or attch  or call my html code into views.py i mean i was able to make he static pagination

eg :

```
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page = 10)
```

like this but now what i want is when i give input to the textbox,, PER_PAGE must be changed according to the given input like 2 records or 4 or n records

i donno whether it is easy or tough but im a starter of python programming and learning still i was unable to make it please help me

Fella student 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
table.paginate(page=request.GET.get("page", 1), per_page = request.GET.get("per_page", 10))
```

That way 10 will be the default value if "per_page" wasn't passed.

Comment: no im getting the default value with the above piece of code which i mentioned in my question i was able to pass that

Comment: my task is they asked me to create a new textfield or textbox so i wrote some thing like this <table class ="paleblue">
       <tr>
          <td>Number of items per page</td>
          <td>{{ chiplet_number}}</td>
          <td width="150">
      </td>
 <td><input class="paleblue" type="submit" value="Apply" /></td>
 </tr>

    <table/>

Comment: now the point is iwas unable to make the input to connect with my views.py

Comment: <table class ="paleblue">
       <tr>
          <td>Number of items per page</td>
          <td>{{ chiplet_number}}</td>
          <td width="150">
          <input type="text" name="Chipletnumber"/>
      </td>
 <td><input class="paleblue" type="submit" value="Apply" /></td>
 </tr>

    <table/>